# Read CSV with extra commas and no quotechar with Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Data:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = '''ID,Level,QID,Text,ResponseID,responseText,date_key
375280046,S,D3M,Which is your favorite?,D5M0,option 1,2012-08-08 00:00:00
375280046,S,D3M,How often? (at home, at work, other),D3M0,Work,2010-03-31 00:00:00
375280046,M,A78,Do you prefer a, b, or c?,A78C,a,2010-03-31 00:00:00'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

Error received:

```
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 3, saw 9
```

It's very obvious why I'm receiving this error. The  data contains text such as `How often? (at home, at work, other)` and `Do you prefer a, b, or c?`.

How does one read this type of data into a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, as I write the question, I figured it out. Rather than delete it, I'll share it with my future self when I forget how to do this.

Apparently, pandas default `sep=','` can also be a regular expression.

The solution was to add `sep=r',(?!\s)'` to `read_csv` like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=r',(?!\s)')
```

The `(?!\s)` part is a *negative lookahead* to match only commas that don't have a following space after them.

Result:

```
          ID Level  QID                                  Text ResponseID  \
0  375280046     S  D3M               Which is your favorite?       D5M0   
1  375280046     S  D3M  How often? (at home, at work, other)       D3M0   
2  375280046     M  A78             Do you prefer a, b, or c?       A78C   

  responseText             date_key  
0     option 1  2012-08-08 00:00:00  
1         Work  2010-03-31 00:00:00  
2            a  2010-03-31 00:00:00
```